# Inverse of hciattach (got HCI over usb, want HCI over UART)

Tags: android, bluetooth

The previous default Bluetooth stack in Android was Bluedroid, which for some odd reason only supports HCI UART and not HCI USB. I have a BT interface that speaks HCI that I've integrated on the driver level (the `hci` device file gets created at least).

If I had a HCI UART device and wanted to convert it to a `hci` node, I'd use `hciattach`. But now I want the inverse - to talk to my HCI USB device using a virtual tty. Is there some way to accomplish this?